# Updating Python Script with Updated Method?

Tags: python, function, methods

I have borrowed a python plugin for an application I am using. The plugin is somewhat outdated in that a method used in script has been changed and I want to try to figure out how to edit the script and make the appropriate updates to the method and functions. There are 4 modules used in the script and i don't know which one contains the method and all its functions

Basically I have a line like this:

```
layerEPSG = layer.srs().epsg()
projectEPSG = self.canvas.mapRenderer().destinationSrs().epsg()
```

The `srs()` method has been changed to `crs()` and some of the functions names have changed as well (but still do the same thing). I want to list them out somehow and see if there is a new names for `epsg()` and `destinationSrs()`

This makes sense in my head, but I don't have a full understanding of how modules, classes, methods, functions all work together. This is a bit of a project to learn more.

Any help is appreciated,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `help()` to give more information about a class or module. As an example:

```
>>> class Fantasy():
...     def womble(self):
...         print('I am a womble!')
...     def dragon(self):
...         """ Make the Dragon roar! """
...         print('I am a dragon...ROAR!')
...
>>> help(Fantasy)
Help on class Fantasy in module __main__:

class Fantasy(builtins.object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  dragon(self)
 |      Make the Dragon roar!
 |
 |  womble(self)
 |
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

Of course, this is more useful if there are doc strings in the class / module.

Comment: Thanks Nick. This really put me in the right direction. much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `dir()` to discover the structure of the modules

```
import layers
# print out the items in the module layers
print dir(layers)
print

x = layer.crs()
# print out the type that crs() returns
print type(x)
# print out the methods on the type returned by crs()
print dir(x)
```

or you can open up the module and read its code.

Comment: Thanks cmd. I don't have much formal coding education. Just self taught. It's these little tools I learn about that help clarify some things I am missing. Thanks a lot.